# Calculate $E(X^2)$ with X uniformly distributed on [-1,2]

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

X is uniformly distributed on $[-1,2]$.
 Hence the density function should be $\frac13$ and E(X) = $0.5$.
 Now I want to calculate $E[X²]$. But to do that I need the density function of $X²$.
 This density function should be $0$ except between $0$ and $4$.
 Is $E[X²]$ uniformly distributed on $[0,4]$?

Comment: "But to do that I need the density function of X²" No, your notes should explain that, for every $g$, $$E(g(X))=\int_\mathbb Rg(x)f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: @Did Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur Because remarks which suffice to answer the question and amount to "Please open your textbook", are not answers to me.

Comment: @Did But they are to the unanswered queue.

Comment: @Arthur I guess there are several ways to make a question exit the unanswered queue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

You do not need the densitfy function of $X^2$. Suppose $f$ is the densify function of $X$.

To compute the expected value of $g(X)$, you can compute $\int_{-1}^2 g(x) f(x) \, dx$.

We just have to compute $\int_{-1}^2 x^2 f(x) \, dx$.

Also, $X^2$ is not uniformly distributed.